# How can one configure Hudson to integrate with Sventon?

Tags: hudson

Hudson ver. 1.353 
Sventon ver. 2.14

I just cannot figure out how to configure Hudson to work with Sventon. It seems that the path format that Hudson expects from Sventon is not the format used by Sventon.

Any ideas?

Thanks.

**UPDATE**

Given an SVN repository with the name of windows, the Sventon URL path to the repository is **http://dev-builder:8080/svn/repos/windows/list/**
However, Hudson expects something like 
**http://dev-builder:8080/svn/repobrowser.svn?name=windows**

Can anyone explain how this should be configured?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regarding configuration, under the **Source Code Management** section of a job configuration, the Repository Browser dropdown lists *Sventon 2.x* as one of the options. (Not trying to be snarky, just making sure you're using the correct configuration.)

There are some [Hudson bugs](http://issues.hudson-ci.org/secure/Dashboard.jspa) (search for sventon) in various states that might be related to your issue.

It's not clear to me whether this is a configuration problem or a Hudson bug. You could post the relevant configuration and both the paths that Hudson generates and Sventon expects. If it is a reproducible Hudson bug, reporting it to the Hudson bug database is the best bet.

---

**Update with my experience**: Under **Source Code Management**, I configured my Repository Browser to be *Sventon 2.x* and set the **Repository URL** to `http://localhost:8080/svn` and **Repository Instance** to `windows`. Hudson then listed changes with Sventon links as `http://localhost:8080/svn/repos/windows/info?revision=XYZ`

I think this means you should set:

- **Repository Browser** to *Sventon 2.x*
- **Repository URL** to `http://dev-builder:8080/svn`, and
- **Repository Instance** to `windows`

Beware that the Hudson inline documentation for Sventon 2.x is wrong about the URLs that will be generated. It looks like this was never updated from 1.x.

Answer (score 0):

You should however be aware that Sventon does not integrate well with projects that have multiple modules from different repositories. We for example use repositories A, B and C. And we've set our repository instance to A so that we can browse to things in that repository but not in any of the other.
Otherwise I really like Sventon as a svn browser.